# RaiseEvent in subclass doesnt work (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, class, events, subclass

So I have a class with eventhandler to help me handle progressbar stages, a subclass with work subs which do the job and I have a subclass with his own events which I just copied from main class.
Problem is event in subclass doesnt work at all. I dont know why really.

Thats how my code looks like:

```
Class FolderHelper

    'Thats my progressbar eventhandler. It is OK
    Private Shared _StageCompleted As Integer

    Public Shared Event MyProgressChanged(ByVal CurStage As Integer)

    Public Shared Property StageCompleted() As Integer
        Get
            Return _StageCompleted
        End Get

        Set(ByVal CurProgress As Integer)
            _StageCompleted = CurStage
            'This event is OK.
            RaiseEvent MyProgressChanged(CurStage)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub RefreshProgress() Handles Me.MyProgressChanged
       'Some progressbar stuff here
    End Sub

    'This is my subclass with malfunction event
    Public Class ParseNames

        Private Shared _FilePath As String

        Public Shared Event NewFilePath(ByVal NewFile As String)

        Public Shared Property FilePath() As String
            Get
                Return _FilePath
            End Get

            Set(ByVal NewFile As String)
                _FilePath = NewFile

                'Problem here. Event doesnt fire. 
                'But its completely copies event in class above.
                RaiseEvent NewFilePath(NewFile)
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub AnalyzeNewFile(ByVal NewFile As String) Handles MyClass.NewFilePath
             'Some work here
        End Sub

    End Class

    'class with some work subs...
    Public class DoWorks

        Private Sub DoWork()
            'Thats what has to call a work

             'This variable set is NOT ok with firing event
             Folder_helper.ParseNames.Filepath = SomeNewFile

             'This one IS ok
             Folder_helper.StageCompleted +=1

        End Sub
    End class

End Class
```

Ok. Oscar goes to Plutonix :)

Comment: `ParseNames` is not a subclass, just a private or internal class.  It is not instanced and there is nothing setup to listen to any events it might raise.  The Shared Props and Subs in can be used (because they are Shared) but you need a WithEvents object variable to catch any events.

Comment: Great! After I've added "Dim WithEvents Shared PN as new ParseNames" and change my variable set to "PN.Filepath = SomeNewFile" all working fine right now. Thanks a lot, man =)

Comment: Answers should not be part of the question - see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code HAS to be like this to work:

```
Class FolderHelper
'Create an instance of my private class which is listening to events
Public Shared WithEvents PN As New ParseNames

Public Class ParseNames
      'Same strings as above...
End class

'All others strings are the same except...

Public class DoWorks

    Private Sub DoWork()

         'I has to call my newly created instance of ParseNames which is "WithEvents"
         PN.Filepath = SomeNewFile
         Folder_helper.StageCompleted +=1

    End Sub
End class
```

End Class

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be nice if you could explain why this solution worked for you. This way your answer would be more useful to future visitors. Also answering your own question without giving credit to the person who was helping you (Plutonix in this case) is discouraged on StackOverflow. Consider asking them to post an answer and accept that instead. You are free to publish your answer beside it, if you wish.